# Picture references from MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to buid a Php site that show data from my MySQl database.

and i think im almost there, everything works except the Pictures.

i cant get my php site to show the pictures with the picture reference from Sql database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db1");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>untitled</title>


</head>

<body>


<div class="content">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id, Producent, Model, kategori FROM tb1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `tb1");
echo "<table>";
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";?> <img scr="<?php echo $row["Billedurl"]; ?>"/> <?php echo "        </td>";
echo "<td>" .$row["Producent"] .$row["Model"]; echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";


}
echo "</table>";



mysqli_close($con);
?>
<!-- end .content --></div>
<!-- end .container --></div>
<div class="footer"><br>
<!-- end .footer --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not currently fetching column `Billedurl` to put in `img` tag. Add thid column in your `SELECT` query.

Comment: How do i do it the right way then ?

Comment: can you share an example of what the `Billedurl` field contains in the db and confirm that the path exists?

Comment: You should not edit the original question with information from the answers as then the answers will stop making sense. Instead, you should add what you have tried and how it has failed below the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to select all the columns you are going to use, so if you need `Billedurl`, you should change:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, Producent, Model, kategori FROM tb1";
```

to:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, Producent, Model, kategori, Billedurl FROM tb1";
```

Now the value of that column will be available in `$row["Billedurl"]`.

**Edit:** It seems that now you have the correct value in your html, but the path to the image is not correct as it is a relative path.

You should prefix your variable with the correct folder so that the image is found by the browser. That can be as simple as just using an absolute path but that depends on where the `pic/` directory is located.

So if your variable contains `pic/l_jabra_evolve80.jpg"` and the `pic/` folder is on the root of the web-server, you can do something like:

```
# before the loop
$imagePrefix = '/';

    # in the loop
     ... <img scr="<?php echo $imagePrefix . $row["Billedurl"]; ?>"/>  ...
```

Now the browser will try to fetch the image from `/pic/l_jabra_evolve80.jpg`.

Comment: @C.Hansen. That's not very helpful: What does your database structure look like and what does a complete row contain?

Comment: @C.Hansen. If you've tried it, may you edit your question to keep us updated, please?

Comment: @Jeroen. Im not quiet sure what you are asking of me. i dont get any errors when opening my php page. it shows textfields from the database, just not the picture. a complete row shows "Producent,Model,Billedurl"

Comment: @C.Hansen. And what is stored in the `Billedurl` column, can you give some examples? Perhaps the only problem is that the path is not correct because it is relative or incomplete.

Comment: @jeroen in BIlledurl i store the URL adress for the picture. example "pic/l_jabra_evolve80.jpg"

Comment: @C.Hansen. That's a relative path, are you sure that is correct from where you open the php page? And can you confirm that by now you at least see that address in the html source of the generated page?

Comment: Yes, i can confirm that i see the correct url in the browser source code.

Comment: @C.Hansen. So the path is wrong / incomplete, see my edit.

Comment: @jeroen. the path is correct. if i type in my ul in my browser Localhost/pic/l_jabra_evolve80.jpg. it show the picture correct. i also tryed to use an url from an extern website, thats not working .

Answer (score 0):

You need to do little bit of debugging:

first change little bit in your query

```
 $sql = "select * FROM tb1";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
```

Then try to check `print_r($result)` and check if you are getting everything here or not.